# Why is the LR Instagram app for Lightroom telling me constantly to update the app?

Tags: plugins, upload, adobe-lightroom

My LR Instagram plug-in from Adobe Lightroom constantly keeps asking to update it. I even uninstalled the plug-in completely. It uploaded exactly two images and then it told me again to update my app.

Steps Ive done:
- removed photos
- readded them to the collection
- reconfigured lightroom plug-in
- reinstalled lightroom plug-in
- reinstalled lightroom

Best regards and thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why the publish action might fail.

First of all, check if your instagram plugin is out of date.

Next you can check the following things (which will lead to instagram rejecting your photo)

- check if you gave a title for the photo
- check if you added a caption for the photo
- check if your caption contains at least one non-tag and one #tag
- if the three above points are true, you might try to crop your image or resize it (although i never had problems with that)

best regards,

Julian

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error I delete some of my keywords (which convert to #tags. I especially target problematic keywords like ones with spaces in them and Lightroom's keyword<_distinctions.

I think there's a limitation to how many tags you can convert to Instagram, so try removing keywords until it works. I usually go down to twenty-something keywords for it to work.